# Setup single record MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, row, record

How to set a single record to a user profile? For example username, password, email, and wallet. I need to show only date for each user login. This script shows wallet but first user id person and I need to show the user who is logged in.

HTML and PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql","root","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT wallet FROM users LIMIT 1");


echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>wallet</th>

</tr>";

while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['wallet'] . "</td>";


echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause to the query, so you only fetch the row for the user who is logged in.

Comment: How do you know _user who is logged in now_???

Comment: can you give me code example

Comment: <?php
/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
  header("location: error.php");    
}
else {
    // Makes it easier to read
    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $active = $_SESSION['active'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

Answer (score -1):

To answer you fully.

Start by updating your user table when your users log in by changing the status true or false depending on your implementation.

Also start a session
your code now becomes

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $con=mysqli_connect("mysql","root","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

//Login logics
 $res= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users where username='user' and password ='pass'");
if($res)
{
   $user = mysql_fetch_row($res);
//Keep track of the current logged in user
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user['id'];
}
//Now your logic to get wallet or any other thing for the current logged in user
$currentUser = $_SESSION['user'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT wallet FROM users where id=".$currentUser.");


    echo "<table border='0'>
    <tr>
    <th>wallet</th>

    </tr>";

     $record = mysqli_fetch_row($result)

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record['wallet'] . "</td>";


    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Hope this helps..

Work with the Edit you dont need the While loop since you are looking for just a record

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /customers/6/7/1/itube.one/httpd.www/profile.php on line 91    (line 90
                 91while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                 92{